# Hadoop view created with CTE misbehaves

Tags: hadoop, view, common-table-expression

Here is the view definition(Runs fine. View gets created)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view 
AS WITH Q1 
AS (SELECT MAX(LOAD_DT) AS LOAD_DT FROM load_table WHERE UCASE(TBL_NM) = 'FACT_TABLE') 
SELECT F.COLUMN1
, F.COLUMN2
FROM   Q1, FACT_TABLE F 
WHERE  Q1.LOAD_DT = F.TRAN_DT
;
```

However, when run

```
SELECT * from my_view;
```

getting following error message:

> FAILED: SemanticException Line N:M Table not found 'Q1' in definition of view my_view....etc..

Looks like hive is trying to treat the Q1 (which is CTE) as a physical table. Any ideas how to work around this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the similar issue in our environment. To answer your question, it's a bug in Hive. Fortunately, we have a workaround to make it work. If you were using impala and hive and both are using same metastore. Create the view in Impala and it will work on both hive and impala.

Reason:
Hive is appending your database name to the CTE reference created which is causing the issue.

Thanks,
Neo